# react not reactively updating on login

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

```
import storeFactory from '../../store/index'

{storeFactory().getState().auth.isLoggedIn == true &&
        <div>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
}
```

I won't use a component there, I just want conditional rendering, and it works, as long as I refresh the page. When I log in/out h1-Hello-h1 won't change.

How to make it reactive without class&component&render ...?

Comment: why not use a component to render this?

Comment: You'll have to use `store.subscribe()` to be notified of changes. http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe